# m3u8 twitch stream, raw data from stream

Tags: java, http, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

So I have been developing a program using java, and can get the m3u8 playlist. 
for example result like this

```
[  
   {  
      "resolution":"1920x1080",
      "url":"https://video-weaver.ord02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CtAD4rHFHwfN46oCHLZPftpNiWjhfc4GGgXWqonqVwWUxD5tLQmrcIlRuFoOX3q7wSBFrAyW3WH_5kATHdruy2KyNLZ7YjLGTRZC74_3CEUclrqmYRIX5J8O8L5B7xjGnHBuifu51zL66MGI71-jZ8LD5Gwh7IS9l99iDOk68ArGNAeZpX2th5IduC3ZY8OUd9FPDFHZbVCj1DM-ekxTZ15XCXR6N7xjc-6buqW-BVyz9JIlU9eGY5yAJK1kV8FU9VwkCs9YvgQLb2d-m2yyjZjss_1F90BRT8UEKtNklsCtJ1rjCf_TafgXlpcTTFA5t-_ZbwARhktqDWO-P2M2gSFwX2ZM9UKmA6vgxPFNuzCU_pPRvsjaiyOF3ABYQoqY62Szx1lJ_PnSYjnGZ4QoODHoyoFUK8PYiQXmOCJ4AVA2L_qb1gf9p90N6Wlv_xC-jyBW6WBF9bop3gJOU7wW2Avoo7558PjCejUrfPD8zeVdaQ_-hNjwgEdW66Wcgf76I54oq12Yxqr92jud9nl8wWczE_VF34Vj-sE42amnCpPVRSa1k90vBqTMTtYQhzrKyBwXvo8weiG7IqfUgnTcOSAJ9iSmBEy8X5BDlO0IJnqGxSISEMhdoq5caAcX0P_kS-VNcTcaDIIkF3nLCeNvVjc-YQ.m3u8",
      "quality":"1080p60 (source)"
   },
   {  
      "resolution":"1280x720",
      "url":"https://video-weaver.ord02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/Cs4DYFO5mZfiMBfkTGBPLey3DbKgl_LLj8f5Q5c80CYY2ncSMfHexOpzHkJg5uMoP6KPQKhkBmBmea6mldd4K2tYVWI5OKXMn-QhJ0BF-2S78B1OQI12uNWQnJWYQDM1bMo2zZ0u78p_Gyk2P5omSuxBX_J_4xcRr1by_33_CX0WAH3DDS1JQGk5_pnz4wvVB1UgMshtgQ7BI1Dtz8t85q3swXSdnSKKQC_r8msaOHtoa6W1GZ7iaWdC7wJjnPsqxEvbJctvjLFDF_KVQ0l8x-S1vhexTvueoh0VLuuqZKhbWP3v8A4r73APDlDKK1d8MV0pDIfGwIHW5PBLHP4MQdY7nNjOlzGvHggjbbG8yGDmbVNgAYZRNZolJFLFDBEmsYNP2FM9jeEINj6rX_8lI1rYhnSYHe9XUM2W8HIoCQmktLZx6vW-fg7nXLYydzB_CEc8Ad7z6wrsBOPK7syK1lzo_jUxCy7arWNc-CH70kRBy5EP9p7WNo-CKHtW0HSqcaTJccDlQgJ_ntoQvN4OGxHC27ojr8_KM-kJGOcqahG4bKY-LYput2s29fcvJPelOQcPKIXm3Z1qmt8L3t42Ny17cdMzlvNauIzR-xfGl1rbEhCfcEt1e2QGyBFarxGh9MsXGgzjMHIpTTu1rkeD3Vs.m3u8",
      "quality":"720p60"
   },
```

And I am curious how I would go about receiving raw data from this stream, in such a way that I can then deal with that data myself. Such as the way that VLC is able to take a file / web location of either of those and show the video that is being displayed in the stream. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: You load the specificed playlist and start processing it as a playlist should be done, with polling and downloading segments.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen do you have any example of this?

Comment: No, but it’s a simple format and your favorite search engine will surely find the definition. Asking for external resources is off topic here and explaining the whole thing would make this a very broad answer.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen do you know of any examples of converting a .ts imagefile to bufferedimages[] or something? Something that can point me in that direction, I have the parsing and all that good, but they use .ts as the return data format.